# Can a local ODBC data source be set to automatically clone to a remote mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, odbc

First off, I apologize for my lack of knowledge in this particular area. I am attempting to have a remote mysql database interact with a MS Access database that is located on a local machine via ODBC. (I'm stuck using this format because it interacts with a particular software  on the local machine)  I would need the local Access database to automatically update the remote mysql database every hour or some other specified amount of time.  Is there a php script that can run like a cronjob to sync the two dbs or some other alternative method to get the same effect? Thanks in advance for any info and help on this matter.